# I'm wanting to have a female Betta sorority and Corydras- would that be over crowding?

Tags: aquarium, fish, freshwater, aquatic-plants

I have a 3ft tank, it's been cycling for about a week so far. We want to have a female Betta sorority(at least 5 females) and at least 2 bottom feeders (Corydras). Would this be considered overcrowding?

Yes the tank is underplanted for a sorority and I intend to get some tall growing plants for the back. I want a fairly neat looking plant to go with 
the tank. Perhaps Jungle Vallisneria?

[image]

Comment: When you say '3ft tank' does that mean it is a cube so ~ 764 litres? To answer the question about overcrowding we need to know the volume of the tank not necessarily one dimension (if it isn't a cube)

Answer (score 3):

You should be okay with that fish load, as long as you follow weekly or at least bi-weekly partial water changes (10-20%) and gravel vacuuming. If you want to get real nerdy pick up some test kits for nitrites, nitrates, and ammonia, and monitor their levels (all are bad for fish health...). Water changes dilute these, and gravel vacuuming removes fish waste that causes their buildup. Also - you can test your source water for these pollutants - sometimes well water (and even municipal water...) can be high in nitrates from the start, so your baseline nitrate level will not be zero...!

I would recommend having as much water as possible in the tank. The more water in an aquarium system, the more stable the conditions will be. Maybe there is a good reason your tank is a few inches shy of being full, but if not bring the water all the way up to the tippy-top.

Answer (score 1):

I assume for that size it's about 150-180 litres? 
If that's the case, I don't think that you're overcrowding. You might even want to add a few more corydoras. 
They like to live in groups, so 2 is a bit too few. Try at least 6...

Betta's also like to have some floating plants the hide under. I've had some Riccia fluitans floating in my tank. But other plans are also suitable.

Good job on cycling the tank first. And like Paul mentioned: don't forget to test the water before you add the fish.

Comment: Yeah, we now have 2 corydoras and will deffinetly be getting some more! And yes I really want floating plants, but my mum didn't- I'll make sure any way. Thanks:)